# In Vim, how to display the text of a line with a specific color if it contains a specific word?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have a simple Todo list :

```
141015 Call the office about something
141015 Buy a new tie
141016 Book 2 seats at theater
```

If an item is DONE, I simply delete it.
But if it is in progress - with WIP at the end of the line - I want to keep it in view, with the text just in DarkGray (which, against a black background, seems to be "blurred").

```
141015 Call the office about something WIP (-> whole line in DarkGray)
141015 Buy a new tie
141016 Book 2 seats at theater
```

I came out with (in my syntax.vim) :

```
:syntax region xWip start='^' end='WIP$'
hi xWip ctermfg=DarkGray
```

but then, in my Todo list, everything was grayed

Where did I go wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `:syntax region` is that Vim doesn't check for an end match when starting the region, so every line (because it matches `^`) got highlighted. You can switch to `:syntax match` if you want to stick with syntax highlighting instead of switching to `:match` (as in @evnu's answer), as that command is *window-local*, unlike syntax highlighting.

```
:syntax match xWip "^.*WIP$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:match` for this: `:match Error /^.*WIP$/`. See `:help match` on how to define another hightlight group for different highlighting.

To run the matching automatically, consider using an autocommand:

```
:au BufRead,BufWrite * :match xWip /^.*WIP$/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have been more precise : I want the text of the line - and not the line itself - to be in DarkGray (I shall edit my question). How should I proceed ? Thanks again

Comment: @ThG Just to be clear: you want the part after the timestamp highlighted?

Comment: No, the text of the whole line, including the timestamp, in dark gray.

Comment: I think this is what the command above does. Maybe I am still missing something. `:match xWip /^.*WIP$/` will highlight all lines matching the regexp with the highlight group `xWip`. If that group defines the highlighting to be a dark gray foreground, then the complete line should be in gray.